# How to bind a class that came from another component as a prop

Tags: vue.js

I have these props: `["color", "bg"]`.

The `color` prop has data like this: `{background-color:'red'}`.

I'm trying to bind the color that came from the props.

So instead of:

```
'VJS_controls__volume-bar--active'
```

```
v-bind:class="[{ 'VJS_controls__volume-bar--active': volume >= 0.8 }]"
```

Comment: I understand nothing....Could you please  provide more details

Comment: Does `bg` have any significance here? What is `volume`? The examples at the end don't appear to be related to the rest of the question: could you elaborate on how they are relevant to what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have parent component:

```html
<child-component :bgColor="childBgColor"></child-component>
```

And in child component:

```html
<div v-bind:style="{ background-color: bgColor }">
</div>
```

```js
props: {
 bgColor: String,
}
```